# Filter by data for all pages in a table in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have successfully applied pagination for a table in Angular 2. I have a textbox which is used to filter the rows in the table based on the input text. I am currently showing 10 rows per page. The issue is that when the matching "filter by" text is available in page 2 or 3 then pipe doesn't catch it. It only looks against the data in first page. How can I make it search for all pages of table?

**expense.component.html**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="#column of columns">
                        {{column | case}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#mydata of data | filterBy:listFilter">
                    <td *ngFor="#column of columns">
                        {{mydata[column]}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" style="color:brown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center">
            <ul class="pagination" *ngFor="#count of numberOfPages">
                <li (click)="pageClicked($event)" [class]="currentSelectedPage == count.pageNumber ? 'active' : ''" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <a>{{count.pageNumber}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**pagination.pipe.ts**

```
  import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'paginateBy'
})

export class PaginationPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any[], args: number[]): any[] {        
        let totalCount: number = args[0];
        let currentPage: number = args[1];
        return this.filter(value, args[1], args[0]);        
    }

    private filter(arr: any[], currentPage: number, totalCount: number): any[] {
        let count: number = currentPage * 10;
        let start: number = (currentPage < 2) ? 1 : ((currentPage - 1) * 10);
        let end: number = (currentPage * 10) > totalCount ? totalCount : (currentPage * 10);
        let result: any[] = arr.slice(start, end);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
 import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterBy'
})

export class CommonFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any[], args: string[]): any[] {

        let filter: string = args[0] ? args[0].toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filter ? value.filter((expense: any) => this.filterByAll(expense, filter)) : value;
    }

    private filterByAll(expense: any, filterby: string): boolean {
        for (var key in expense) {
            try {
                if (expense[key].toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterby) != -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                if (expense[key].toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterby) != -1) {
                    return true
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**expense.component.ts**

```
export class ExpenseComponent implements OnInit {
errorMessage: any[];
columns: string[];
data: any[];
totalData: any[];
listFilter: string;
columnInputs: INameValue[] = [];
class: string;
isSuccess: boolean = false;
isFailed: boolean = false;
numberOfPages: any[] = [];    
currentSelectedPage: number;
message: string = "Data could not be saved. Please try again or contact technical team.";

constructor(private _commonService: CommonService, private _expenseService: ExpenseService) {}   


private getPromiseData(data: any[]) {
    this.totalData = this.data = data;
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.round(data.length / 10); i++) {
        this.numberOfPages.push({ pageNumber: i, isSelected: i == 1 ? true : false });
    }
    this.currentSelectedPage = 1;
    this.filterRows(1);
}

pageClicked(event): void {
    this.currentSelectedPage = +event.target.innerText;
    this.filterRows(+event.target.innerText);
}

filterRows(pageNumber: number) {
    let p = new PaginationPipe();
    this.data = p.transform(this.totalData, [this.totalData.length, pageNumber]);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

}

I have deleted some of the non-relevant code from expense.component.ts
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually you are getting the teb rows from table to show on the current page to make the search available for 2nd and 3rd page you have to call the WEB API to get the data. If it is not in current collection and for this you have to create you own method to filter the data and show accordingly on the grid

Comment: If you currently are in the second page, and you apply the filter, wouldn't it get for you the values in the second page? I think the problem here is that you are applying the filter on "data", not on "totalData". Your "data" array only contains the elements in the current page, not all the data

Comment: @rashfmnb: It is available in the current collection just not on the current page.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali: That's right. Filter is getting applied only for current page. I have a variable created which hold the total data but the pipe will send the data only for the current page not the total one.

Comment: Yes, I think the way you are using the pagination pipe is kind of wrong. I have never seen a pipe being used that way outside of the template. I would suggest you do the following: 
in the click page number event, just write currentSelectedPage = count.pageNumber
Then, in the ngFor up in the template, change data to totalData, and chain the pipes like this: "#mydata of totalData | filterBy:listFilter | paginate:totalData.length:currentSelectedPage"
Or something like that